# JAVA timeline for an audioplayer program

Tags: java, timeline

I'm in the process of programming an audioplayer like winamp in Java. I'm in the GUI phase now and need some kind of timeline/timebar, like in winamp and other audio/video playback programs.

Does anyboyd have an idea to what I can use for this? Something already in Java?

Image of winamp's timebar;

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSlider](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JSlider.html) or [JScrollBar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollBar.html) might be candidates, though you'd have to put some work in to get them to look nice!

Comment: Hey! I'm working with JSlider right now, I think it's going to work well.

Comment: @JW_ Glad to hear it! Just to let you know, if you feel this is the right answer to this question (or any other answer appears you feel is the right answer) it's good practice to accept it by ticking the green arrow next to your chosen answer. You get a tiny bit of reputation for doing it too :)